# connect contact form 7 (cf7) to an external API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I'm trying to connect my contact 7 form to post also to an external CRM by using wp_remote_post.  I found a tutorial and came up with this code:

```
function on_submit( $form, &$abort, $submission ) {

    if ( $abort === TRUE ) {
    return;
    }

    //tried seeing what my datafile was but nothing is being posted to my errorlog
    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    ob_start();
    var_dump($posted_data);
    error_log(ob_get_clean());

    $email = sanitize_text_field($data['your-email']);
    $name = sanitize_text_field($data['your-name']);
    $phone = sanitize_text_field($data['your-phone']);
    $message = sanitize_textarea_field($data['your-message']);

    $apiurl = 'https://coolapi.com';
    
    $apiheaders = array(
       'Authorization' => 'Token token=NotMyRealToken'
    );
    $apibody = array( 'marketing_form' => array (
            'email' => $email,
            'first_name' => $name,
            'phone_number' => $phone,
            'notes' => $message,
            'relationship' => 'self',
            'community_id' => 19019,
            'lead_source_id' => 60725
        ));

    $args_for_push = array (
        'headers' => $apiheaders,
     'body' => json_encode($apibody)
    );

    $response = wp_safe_remote_post( $apiurl, $args_for_push );
    $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);

    if ( is_wp_error($response) ) {
        $abort = TRUE;

        //$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
        //$result = json_decode($body);

        $submission->set_response($response->get_error_message() );
        $submission->set_status('api_failed');
    }
    if($response_code != 200) {
        $submission->set_status('api_failed'.$response_code);
        $submission->set_response('Something went wrong: '.$response_code);

    } else {
        $submission->set_status('api_success'.$response_code);
        $submission->set_response('Thank you! we will get back to you shortly. confirm: '.$response_code);

    }
    
    //tried getting my debug info because nothing is reported to my error log. (this did not work)
    $debug="1";
    $mail = $form->prop( 'mail' );
    $new_mail = str_replace( '[your-name]', $debug, $mail );
    $form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $new_mail ) );
    return $form;
}

add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'on_submit', 10, 3);
```

When I run this code without Cf7 the API returns a success code. But here no matter what I do CF7 submits the form and I receive an email but I'm not getting a submission to the CRM nor any errors.  the message at the bottom of the form says: `Thank you for your message. It has been sent.` and no class changes are made to the form.

How can I better dump the log (or response) or have my submissions errors show up on the front so I can see what is wrong? Or better yet, get this thing working!

Comment: why do you need to run `ob_start()`, and what would `$posted_data` be? Shouldn't you `var_dump($data)` instead?

Comment: @Philip.  I tried a var_dump too.  there were other pages that said because the $data file was part of an AJAX request through CF7 then it had to go through the ob_start? Didn't work in either way though!

Comment: I am saying that you should probably just do `error_log(print_r($data, true))` instead of that, and also that you are using the wrong variable - `$posted_data` doesn't exist

Comment: @Philip good point.  Changed to your code, but still nothing.  I have debug on in wp-config too.  the error_log should be in my main wp directory. right?

Comment: error log is in `wp-content` and is the file debug.log. You may have to create the file first. Usually takes anywhere between 0-15 seconds (or more) for it to populuate after a request.

Comment: yeah I found it.  My API is working perfectly.  it's just the response from CF7 isn't what is working.  Trying to figure that out now...if you have any insight on that part?  Otherwise you've already been a big help!